# Check dataRange for duplicate values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I have a datarange "values" below. How can I simply find the duplicates within the datarange. I.E. rows C4/D4 says "something,here" and row C10/D10 says "something,here" it would log my 2 duplicates

```
function checkforDups() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
   var values = sheet.getRange("C2:D100").getValues();

   //Logger.log(values)

   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      Logger.log(values[i]);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Find duplicates

```
function checkforDups() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 3, 99, 2).getDisplayValues();
  let uA = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let x = r.join(',')
    if (!~uA.indexOf(x)) {
      uA.push((x));
    } else {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("#ffff00");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked great I appreciate the help.